# Table doesn't exist on CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a SQL dump to another server.  It fails on the first line.  I'm first creating the `exp_actions` table and then inserting a bunch of data into it, but I get this really weird error.

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `ee_cmssite`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `exp_actions`
--
CREATE TABLE  `exp_actions` (

 `action_id` INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `class` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `method` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
PRIMARY KEY (  `action_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =21;

MySQL said: 

#1146 - Table 'site_ee.exp_actions' doesn't exist
```

Why doesn't it exist?  I just instructed it to be created.  I'm completely baffled.  I've tried with and without `IF_NOT_EXISTS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this seemingly bizarre error - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696069 for the solution.

I had the same symptoms and the cause was the same - moving to a new machine I took the old short-cut of simply copying the databases from the mysql/data directory that I needed directly into the new machine, however some were newer InnoDb types. This causes the Create Table throws table doesn't exist error. I had to drop the database and recreate it, then import from an sql dump.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQL script, the table exists in another database:

> --
>
> ### -- Database: `ee_cmssite`
>
> ### -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> -- Table structure for table `exp_actions`

try to use `ee_cmssite` database instead.

Comment: Nope, didn't fix it.  That's just a comment anyway, so it shouldn't affect it?

Comment: nop, how are you using that script? the creation script has no errors. I really think its a problem of where is created or from where you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

While the error is not clear, I think this is related to the missing `USE` at the beginning of the file. mysqldump doesn't add a `USE` statement when you dump a single db. So you should add:

```
USE `ee_cmssite`;
```