# Cannot access SQL table that I could access before

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been working on a table inside a database, and now I cannot seem to access it. It says that the table "doesn't exist." Any help would be appreciated. Here are steps I'm taking to try and access it.

```
Ajay-Rameshs-iMac:~ ajay$ mysql -u root -pmypassword SOUsers
    mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_sousers |
+-------------------+
| userData          |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from userData;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sousers.userdata' doesn't exist
```

Any help would be much appreciated! In case it's important, I'm running this on OSX Lion Terminal.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: take a look at this, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11696069/26224

Comment: After trying what muratgu said, have you tried  REPAIR TABLE userData USE_FRM ?

Comment: No, I'm the only one who uses the database, since it is on localhost. Also, I tried those commands and they did not work.

Comment: What value does `select @@lower_case_table_names;` return? Is it possible that setting has been changed?