# Delete taking so long in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Delete all the contents from a table. So using `delete from M_Cast`. But it seems to take infinitely long to get executed. The number of rows in the table are just 19. And this is happening only with this particular table M_Cast. What can be the problem..?

Picture of my terminal . I pressed enter and the cursor is still blinking
[image]

Even I faced this problem [MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should) an hour back. I created a new DB as mentioned. But now even when I am trying to delete the DB it doesnt execute.

Why do such weird things happen in MySQL?

Comment: What type of table is this?  innodb, MyISAM, etc... and Can you get the table structure?

Answer (score 1):

If a delete is taking so long on such a small table, then something is presumably locking the table.  Alternatively, you could have indexes or cascading deletes that affects a large number of rows in other tables.

One way of doing this is by using `show open tables` (see the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html)).

As a note.  A faster way to delete all the rows in a table is to use `truncate table`.  This does the deletion without logging or executing `delete` triggers.

Comment: Yeah the table isn't locked nor in use . Yeah I also tried truncate but didn't work.