# Table exist in the mysql folder. mysql error files doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-14.04, repair

My system was crashed. I try to import my database from .frm files. 
I copied those files to my new mysql server location . '/var/lib/mysql'.
I gave the change the priviledge. I had one database.

I just compied the following files to my database foloder name 'my_school'.

1. ibdata1
2. ib_logfile0
3. ib_logfile1

I copied the whole folder to mysql folder location in ubuntu 14.04, **/var/lib/mysql**

I gave the privileges to this folder using this command.

```
chown  mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/my_school -R
```

Then, I try to access the database. I can access the database. I can see the tables. but, it give error when I try to see the table structure or data.

the error it show this is.

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table doesn't exist but both table files (frm, ibd) exists on the file system
```

I used these solutions, these solution doesn't work.

- [MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should?lq=1)
- [MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should)

Please, help.

1. Is .frm file contain both data and structure of the data ?
2. what is purpose of ibdata1 file?
3. what is purpose of ibd_logfile0 and ibd_logfile1 ?

Comment: Try doing a `repair table table_name`