# mysql master-slave partitioned table doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I use [create Raw Data Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto-rawdata.html) for mysql-master-slave replication,after setup,It's return `table xxx doesn't exists` when query on the partitioned tables,but it's work ok on the other tables.

And,When I change to use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto-mysqldump.html), It's all work ok.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the partition table did not work but the other tables did and the mysqldump worked fine, my best guess would be that your Partitioned data is not stored in the same place as the rest of your data.  Thus, when you used the tar, zip, or rsync method to copy your data directory, you left out the data that made up the partitioned table.  You would need to locate where the partitioned data is stored and moved that over along with the rest of the data directory.

Based on your comment below, however, you have what is called the [famous Schrodinger table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should). Based on [Schrodinger's Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) paradox, This is where Mysql thinks that the table exists, because it shows up when you run `show tables`, but does not allow you to query of it; as in it exist but does not exist.

Usually this is as a result of not copy over the metadata (as in the `ibdata1` file, and the `ib_logfiles`) correctly.  One thing that you can do to test this is, if possible, [remove](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44458/how-do-i-remove-partitioning) the [partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) from the tables and try your rsync again.  If you are still getting this error, it has nothing to do with the fact that the table is partitioned.  Then, this test would lead me to believe that you did not copy all the data over correctly.

Comment: thanks,but I'm sure the partitioned data is in the same place,I compare the  whole data directory ,and found the two directory's  file is all same,and `show tables` also list the Partitioned table,but cannot query.

Comment: Thanks again,Now I change the master running on ubuntu  and It's work fine.(on windows8.1 before) ,I guess there's something different between these two os for running mysql,but i can't find the answer.