# Table Name doesn't show up in DB Viewer treeview, but shows up on Query

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

I have a database in SQLYog - MySql GUI, which on expanding in the treeview viewer, shows all the existing tables, but if you query ,say
`show tables from database_name`
It shows a table that isn't in the database treeview.
I tried the query
`SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database_name`,
and it shows `null` for all fields associated with the table.
I think the table was deleted sometime ago, but hasn't been erased from the database logs or something.
 How do I delete this entry, and also, please tell me why this is happening.

Comment: looks similar to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your mysql server suffered a crash, that "table" is probably a view and sqlyog lists it under the views.

Mysql documentation on [show tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) says:

> This statement also lists any views in the database. The FULL modifier is supported such that SHOW FULL TABLES displays a second output column. Values for the second column are BASE TABLE for a table and VIEW for a view.

Mysql documentation on [show table status](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html) says:

> For views, all the fields displayed by SHOW TABLE STATUS are NULL except that Name indicates the view name and Comment says view.

Comment: Thank you.. That really helped.

Comment: In this case can you pls mark the answer as accepted to let other viewers of this topic know that the issue has been resolved?