# XAMPP Error - #1932 - Table '---' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: macos, xampp

I use XAMPP on my Mac. Everything was working well, until for no reason (no updates or new programs and anything) xampp stopped working. The servers wouldn't start. Uninstalled/Reinstalled xampp and now it lists the previous databases and their tables; but doesn't let me dig into the tables.
gives me this error:

## 1932 - Table '---' doesn't exist in engine

New databases work fine though.

I added a new database, it worked fine. Then I copied all files from the previous database into the new database hoping it would work but it didn't.
The files are here:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql

Tried this with 3 different versions of xampp; no luck.

One thing I noticed was that the tables in the databases that don't work and give me the error, do not show the size of that table.

Searched Stackoverflow for similar threads; but they either point to some file that doesn't exist or offer no helpful solutions.

Comment: i am having the same problem, did you find a solution

Comment: @Fanckush No. I had to redo all the things I did. I switched to MAMP. It seems more stable.

Answer (score 0):

before everything you must do step 1 or it might not work ...
this worked just fine for me
step 1 - backup Mysql folder in Xampp -> step2 - go to xampp\mysql\backup and copy all files and folder -> step3 -> paste and replace all in xampp\mysql\data (this way you wont loose your databases) -> step 4 - go to the backup folder from step 1 and copy file ibdata1 , ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 and paste and replace in xampp\mysql\data

[MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should/11696069#11696069)

Comment: The solution you provided is misleading. He has issues on mac OS, not windows

Comment: ok , this was a while ago , but if i remember i followed the info from the link and with the information i got i did those steps . I think in linux would be the same , what matters here is the order you do it ( if i remember right). it doesnt matter if you are in windows or in linux . Im on Windows .