# INSERT throw errors

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, phpmyadmin

I'm developing an API with Nodejs and I have a create project endpoint and a create patient endpoint. Both of them work if I create the database tables with mySql.

But I need to run first create project which creates some tables to be used by create user endpoint. The problem comes when I call user endpoint and throws this:

```
** Connection to project psapp_demo successfully.
*** Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'psapp_demo_proposa58_pr.displayer_patient' doesn't exist
```

But database `psapp_demo_proposa58_pr` and table `displayer_patient` exist and are accessible throw PHPmyadmin.

Code for creating a new patient is based on a promise which is catching the error:

```
Services.user.create(connection,req,userId,req.body,clinicId)
.then((userId) => { req.userId = userId; next() })
.fail((err) => next(err))
```

Anyway, database created with a project endpoint also does not work with phpmyadmin so problem seems to realy on the database, not the code. This is the error where you can see I can even navigate with phpmyadmin throw that databases but are not located when I try to insert something:

[image]

A `SELECT` operation throws empty which is right. With a `SELECT`, there is not error.

Do you know why could it be happening? Thanks

Comment: No I'm not, as you can see in the image, even with the db showing in the tree and accessing to the create new register, but it throws an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should)

Comment: Have you restarted the sql server?