# mysql's got a bug show table is see table select cannot see table

Tags: java, mysql

[image]

The test found that navicat was able to browse the table information normally!

Answer (score 0):

Did you move your MySQL db directory to another place? If you do so, and you got a InnoDB table, you need to move your *ib files too and ensure that they are there e.g. (lbdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1).

Related question:

[MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should)