# MySQL "Table doesn't exist", but it actually does

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I've set up a new RDS MySQL instance and an EC2 instance on AWS. When I run the Laravel migration, the database is set up correctly and the tables are created. I can verify this by signing in and seeing the tables in the database in the terminal. But when I try to run a signup request and create a new user, it returns with an error of "table does not exist".

The issue could be that the database is named "OrchidEats" and in the error, it states that "orchideats.users" does not exist. But I am not sure why this could affect it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should can help, hope it does.

Comment: sounds like u already know what the problem is. Just test with lower case db, and see if it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive

Comment: but the database I have set up in the .env file is OrchidEats. Why does it change to orchideats in the error?

Comment: How are you running it locally? via `php artisan serve`?

Comment: no, it's running on aws ec2 and rds. I've signed in using ssh into the ubuntu server

Comment: Have you assigned a user to the database and given it full permissions?

Comment: Yes I did using this link as a tutorial. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SettingUp.html

Comment: Share the Code on GitHub and I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table name user or users.

If user that time open User model file and add this line.

```
protected $table = 'user';
```

Try this code