# Database error with Java Spring boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mariadb

I am trying to run a Java Spring Boot survey project (Maven Architecture) in my local machine by following steps --

1. mvn clean package
2. connect to created jar file

> java -jar target/filename.jar

3. Open browser and browse to localhost:8080

Project is running ok, I can input survey data, but I am getting following error while trying to show result data from database --
[image: Database error]

Although I have found that the table "stressresult" already exist in database --
[image: Table with data]

What's wrong here? Can anybody kindly help?

**Local Machine** -->
OS: Debian 11.x 64-bit
Database: MariaDB 10.6.5
Web server: nginx
Java: Oracle JDK 17

Comment: Do any of the answers to this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should ?

Comment: No, none of the thing suggested in that post solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB is case-sensitive for table names by default. From your screenshot it looks like your query is trying to access `STRESS.STRESSRESULT` instead of `stress.stressresult`.

There is an option to lower-case all table names by default:

Try putting this in your config:

```
[mariadb]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

That should fix your issue.

Detailed info about this parameter can be found here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#lower_case_table_names

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks 