# MySQL + Docker Compose - Create database after dropping gives database exists error

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker compose file in which I create a MySQL container:

```
database:
  image: mysql:5.7
  command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  expose:
    - "3306"
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: docker
  volumes:
    - ./data/${PROJECTNAME}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

My SQL init script simply does the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE User;
CREATE DATABASE Application;
```

When the containers are setup, the data is stored in a data directory in my environment project for the relevant project, so for a project called "base2" the structure ends up looking like this:

[image]

I can connect to the databases fine, but I have encountered some issues which I'm not sure whether they relate to my docker-compose setup or something else. When I run:

```
DROP DATABASE Application;

CREATE DATABASE Application;
```

Throws an error: `Can't create database 'Application'; database exists`. I see similar errors when dropping and recreating tables too.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should/11696069#11696069) to someone asking a similar question states that the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` need to be in the root `mysql` directory - in this case I can see those files are present so I wasn't able to resolve this when researching similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permision like below to your local directory

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql ./data/${PROJECTNAME}/mysql